# Adding angular function to a dynamic dom element

Tags: angularjs, html, css, dynamic, daterangepicker

I am using `daterangepicker` plugin. There's a `Apply` button in the daterangepicker jsp file which can be shown only via inspect element and probably is dynamic.
I can style that particular class. But how to add a `ng-click` function to that particular class?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Use the [angular wrapper](https://github.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker) for the plugin. You can use `apply.daterangepicker` handler for that